# How to correctly read X509 trusted CA in PEM format using openssl

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, x509

I'm having issues trying to read a certificate list. The code I have now is

```cpp
UniqueSsl<BIO> trustedCertificatesBio(BIO_new_mem_buf(trustedCertificates.c_str(), trustedCertificates.size()));
UniqueSsl<X509> tmpCert;
while ( tmpCert = UniqueSsl<X509>(PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX(trustedCertificatesBio.get(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr)) )
{
    X509_STORE_add_cert(trustedStore.get(), tmpCert.get());
}

if (ERR_GET_REASON(ERR_peek_last_error()) != PEM_R_NO_START_LINE)
{
    captureOpensslErrorAndThrow("Failed to add certificate to the trusted X509_STORE");
}
```

*Remarks:* `UniqueSsl` and `captureOpensslErrorAndThrow` are just an helper method/template. Doesn't mean nothing here.

Well, the code is quite simple. I'm just looping through all the certificates inside the `trustedCertificatesBio` and trying to add them to the Trusted Store.

This code was working in production for a long long time and yesterday it stopped. The final value always was returning the `PEM_R_NO_START_LINE` meaning that we reach the EOF.
Since yesterday, one of my clients always get the value 0 (normally means no error) on the final certificate.

This begs me a question: the loop right above is right? Should I check the reason inside the loop, or need to expect the zero as a possible return value of success?

What is the correct way of adding certificates into the Trusted Store?

Thanks!

Comment: *"yesterday it stopped"* -- Well, computers don't get tired and change their behavior. So what changed? Your input data? Compare the old to the new. The OpenSSL version? Bisect it.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yeah! I agree with you. Yesterday I lost basically my day trying to figure out what happened. I'm using the same OpenSSL library and exactly the same version, the code didn't change and the Trusted CA I'm loading in that method is exactly the same (this CA is on git). But the main question is: this loop is right?

Comment: but it's clear that it's not your code . may be call guy who'd written  it then? overall: really lowgrade stuff

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин What is your point? The guy who wrote this doesn't know if this loop is 100% correct that's why I'm here.